# Generic method to get ASP.NET not checked items in checkbox list or radiobutton list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method to get what items are not checked in a checkbox list like so:

```
public static string[] GetNotSelectedCheckboxes(CheckBoxList list)
{
    ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < list.Items.Count; counter++)
    {
        if (!list.Items[counter].Selected)
        {
            values.Add(list.Items[counter].Value);
        }
    }
    return (String[])values.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

I now have a requirement to get not selected items in a radiobutton list, I copied the same method and instead of having a `CheckBoxList` as parameter I have a `RadioButtonList`.

```
public static string[] GetNotSelectedRadioButtons(RadioButtonList list)
{
    ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < list.Items.Count; counter++)
    {
        if (!list.Items[counter].Selected)
        {
            values.Add(list.Items[counter].Value);
        }
    }
    return (String[])values.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

Now the code does exactly the same thing and I read a bit about generic methods, is this where I should use one? I had a look at it but didn't get the syntax right and I'm not sure how to use **list.Items** if I don't specifically specify it as a radio or checkbox list.

Should I use a generic method here and any input on how I should go on about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Generics... but in this case, it seems easier just to use polymorphism using the base class for the simple data list controls

```
public static string[] GetNotSelectedRadioButtons(ListControl list)
```

If you want to implement generics:

```
public static string[] GetNonSelectedItems<T>(T list) where T : ListControl
{
    ... do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Ok ListControl is obviously the easiest way, wasn't aware of that. Thanks!